# How to pass Dynamic IMongoQuery in c# controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have pass a Query using ImongoQuery as userInfoDataQuery in the below method. 
but i don't know how to filter this query in a collection.

```
public IQueryable<UserInfo> UserInfoDataByQuery(IMongoQuery userInfoDataQuery)
{
    if (ServerIsDown) return null;
    UserInfoList.Clear();
    **var filter = Builders<UserInfo>.Filter.And(userInfoDataQuery);** //getting Error in this Line
    var userData = db.UserInfo.Find( filter).ToList();
    if (userData.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (UserInfo item in userData)
        {
            UserInfoList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    var result = UserInfoList.AsQueryable();
    return result;
}
```

How to pass the Filter as IMongoQuery in order to provide dynamic filter for a method?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @DavidPilkington The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinitionBuilder<Models.UserModels.UserInfo>.And(params MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition<Models.UserModels.UserInfo>[])' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work? as Query object takes IMongoQuery as a parameter.

```
  var filter = Query.And(userInfoDataQuery);
```